# Material design wave effect not applied to dynamically created button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-material-design

I am trying to create buttons by using jQuery's `append` method. However the buttons which where created by jQuery don't have the wave effect if I click on them. The button that I created in HTML has the wave effect.

Why is it different? How can I get the wave effect to also appear for the button which is created by jQuery?

Thanks for your help!

```js
$('#line').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Button created by js</button>');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.5/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
  Button
</button>

<hr id="line">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.5/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Waves effect from the MDBootstrap library is not automatically applied to dynamically created elements. You need to instantiate it manually on the new button. As per the [documentation](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/waves-effect/) you can achieve that in your case by calling `Waves.attach('.btn', ['waves-light']);`.

Also note that, as @VVV stated in the comments, `<hr>` is primarily used to define a thematic break in an HTML page, using `after()` instead of `append()` would be better as this code will not validate through W3C.

```js
$('#line').after('<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Button created by js</button>');

Waves.attach('.btn', ['waves-light'])
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.5/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
  Button
</button>

<hr id="line">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.5/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```